# In a Pythagorean triplets, is $a + b$ always greater then $c$?

Tags: project-euler

I have a looked around, but the answer is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Yes. $a+b = \sqrt{(a+b)^2} > \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ = c.

Comment: Yes, because $(a+b)^2> a^2+b^2=c^2$

Comment: Also, one can view it in terms of the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The easiest way to see this is to remember that they correspond to the three sides of a right triangle. The sum of two sides has to be larger than the remaining side. There are also algebraic proofs.